# Shuffling of MySQL record on page refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website where i have two types of offer (best offer and hot offer) fetching from database. I have limited the record to 1.  So that one only one record of hot offer and one record of best offer should view to user. Now I have to shuffle the each offer in page refresh. That is, when any one refresh the page, the next hot offer (from database) should replace the previous hot offer and should be same in best offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to the end of your MySQL query IFF your table is small.

If it is large then this is a very inefficient way of doing it (since it still evaluates every row) so you'd be better off counting the number of rows:

```
SELECT MAX(id), COUNT(*) FROM table
```

and then picking a random id (`$id = rand(1,$count);`) and then selecting that row

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id
```

If there are deleted rows (and this last command returns nothing) then pick a random ID again and run the previous command again. The `COUNT(*)` in the first query is so you can ensure that there is at least 1 row.

This does not work well for tables where there are a lot of deleted rows, plus it assumes that you have an `auto_increment` field.

Comment: $offer_query="select * from offer Where offer_type='2'LIMIT 1";
      $offer_result=mysql_query($offer_query) or die("Error");
     while($rowoffer=mysql_fetch_array($offer_result)){  }                                                      The above one is my query..Now how i have to use count??

Comment: $offer_query="select * from offer Where offer_type='2'LIMIT 1"; $offer_result=mysql_query($offer_query) or die("Error"); while($rowoffer=mysql_fetch_array($offer_result)){ }


The Above one is my code.
Now how to use $count here??

Answer (score 2):

Make it Random, otherwise you have to maintain state of offer displayed on page to get next offer.
Below Query will help.

```
SELECT * from tbl_offers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```